# Table update getting impacted due its presence in view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-update

I have a view something like this:

```
select a.col1, b.col2, c.sum(col3) 
from A a 
join B b on a.id = b.id
join C c on c.id = a.id 
join D d on d.id = c.id and d.col4 in ('A', 'B')
group by a.col1, b.col2;
```

When I try to update in table D using:

```
update D 
set col4 = 'some logic';
```

Then this query takes a lot of time.

If I simply remove the condition `d.col4 in ('A','B')` from my view, query works fine.

Can somebody please suggest what needs to be done

Comment: A `VIEW` would only impact an `UPDATE` on an underlying table if it were an indexed view, and then removing the `IN` clause would promote *more* rows to the `VIEW`. Does the understanding table have an index on it as well, that would aid the view's index?

Comment: Yes it is an indexed view...underlying table does bot have any index except primary key on id field

Comment: I would start by adding some indexes on the table then, as that'll help the `VIEW` reindex; at the moment it will have to rescan the **entire** table.

Comment: Table D is very small , it contains only about 350 records, while table A and C are quite big

Comment: I think the issue is that updating that field in D causes the indexed view to be re-run/recalculated. If you don't have the condition `d.col4 IN ....` then updating col4 doesn't affect the view, so it won't need recalculation.

Comment: Thanks @seanb. Is there any workound so that index is not re-run/recalculated

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, it is likely that this is due to the indexed view needing to be recalculated.

The indexed view (like normal indexes) is kept up-to-date when data changes - the updates are done within the same command/transaction.

With the condition `and d.col4 in ('A', 'B')`, if you update d.col4, then it will trigger an update to the indexed view.

It has been brought up before here on SO e.g., https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163538/an-indexed-view-slows-updates-to-a-crawl-is-there-a-hint-to-work-around-it

It's also not always very predictable e.g., https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/03/indexed-views-data-modifications/

Note that your update command `update D set col4 = 'some logic';` updates every row in D and will trigger a complete re-calculation of the indexed view. I'm presuming this is not your normal situation, but from what you've said

- The other tables have lots of rows
- D only has 350 records
- ... which implies that updating even one row in D will update a lot of rows in the indexed view

Logic suggests to me that you basically have four choices: elimination, mitigation, delaying, and accepting.

What you can do depends on

- Where the indexed view is being used (and how important it is)
- Whether you are allowed to change the indexed view - as well as the other things that rely on it
- How quickly you need the data updates in 'D' done. Alternatively, how important it is that the data is up-to-date (and whether it's more important that D is up-to-date vs a report that is OK being a bit out-of-date)

For example, it will be a very different answer depending on whether the indexed view is used many times by users all the time and must be up-to-date (e.g., it's part of a key report on a dashboard), vs a report that is run infrequently and is fine if it has data as at midnight last night.

**Elimination - getting rid of the indexed view**

If having D up-to-date, and updates to D are important that they run fast, then this may be the better way. Alternatively, if the indexed view isn't really doing much or used much, this also could be the best approach.

*- Get rid of the indexed view and make it a normal view.*

This will speed up your updates, but will slow down anywhere which uses the indexed view.

If the indexed view is important, and important it runs fast with the latest data, then you probably cannot do this.

*- Make the indexed view into a standalone table, updated on a schedule*

This can work if it's not important for the indexed view to have latest data. Instead of having an indexed view, have a process that populates a reporting table regularly (e.g, every 5 minutes, every hour, or every day at 2:00am). This table is then used in reports etc.

**Mitigation - reduce the impact**

In these, you modify how the indexed view works. Your updates to D will still be slow, but not as much.

*- Index tweaks*

Review the execution plans, statistics etc when you run the SQL for the indexed view. Are there any places you can create indexes on any of the relevant underlying tables (A, B, C, D) that will speed up the view?

*- Indexed view tweaks*

It may be possible to modify the indexed view to 'do a bit less' e.g.,

- Removing the group-by may be able to do D updates run a lot faster (or it may not, depending on the exact view)
- Remove D from the view, and instead link it (as needed) when reporting

These 'compromise' between the update and the view by making the indexed view do less. But this means whenever the view is used, it will take longer as it has more work to do.

**Delaying**

If it's not important that D is always up-to-date, you could delay the updates to D by instead creating a process where they are put into a queue and instead are updated later.

**Accepting**

How often do you update D? Does it really matter that it takes a long time to do so? If it's done infrequently, and you can take the delay, then just live with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. These really helped me a lot in further digging up the situation